# Does Ibliss still pray to God?

Tags: salat, allah, shaitan

Ibliss he was very truthful to God before Adam.
My question does Ibliss still pray to Allah or has he stopped?

Comment: Interesting question, but what makes you think he could still be praying? As he is a Jin and basically only pretended being "guided" ... I wouldn't even assume he ever prayed, all we know is that he was asked to do sujud and didn't follow the order, this is no link for praying as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Do we not have jewish references that state that Iblees held an elevated place in the heavens due to his worship of Allah and was among the angels despite being a jinn? That would mean he prayed/worshiped in the past. We do not know if he still prays or not but he knows the Quran as he taught one of the Sahaba the ayatul kursi.

Comment: @Ahmed I really don't know whether there is such a reference. ... you refer to the story of abu Hurairrah I guess.

Comment: @Medi1Saif About the jinns, it is from Jewish traditions. Related video from 0:16 to 2:00

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTEU160orz0

W.r.t. Ayatul Kursi, yes akhi, I'm referring to the Hadiths about Abu Huraira and Satan.

Comment: I'm certain I've read in hadith along the lines of "there was not a handspans length in the universe where Iblis didn't go and worshipped Allah".

Comment: Quran 2 116

And they have said, " Allah has taken to Him a child." All Extolment be to Him! No indeed, He has whatever is in the heavens and the earth. All are devout to Him,

DEVOUT -

having or showing deep religious feeling or commitment.
"she was a devout Catholic"

Answer (score 0):

## Worshipping

To Worship is to submit willingly or unwillingly to the Worshipped (Allah).

**By abiding to what He commanded, doing what He enjoins, and avoiding what He forbids.**

Commands of Allah are for goodness of Mankind and Jinn, on a personal level for them, or a mass/public level.

In other words, worshipping Allah, shall result in goodness to oneself level or society level.

### Ibadaat (Worshipping) is counted as obedience if done willingly.

Prayer is an example of personal worship act. That must be done **willingly** to be rewarded.

### Shaytan Believes in Allah but is Fasiq (disobedient)

Shaytan witnessed the command to prostrate to Adam, was addressed by Allah, and is fully aware that Allah is creator. no doubts here, but he disobeyed Allah! and chose not to abide! Allah described him as **fasiq**.

> 18:50 And [mention] when We said to the angels, "Prostrate to Adam,"
>   and they prostrated, except for Iblees. He was of the jinn and
>   **departed from the command of his Lord**. Then will you take him and his
>   descendants as allies other than Me while they are enemies to you?
>   Wretched it is for the wrongdoers as an exchange.

## Two Types of Worshipping

### Willingly

This is done because you want to abide by what Allah commanded. you're **rewarded** for, and questioned if broke it.
it has two categories:

**Ibadaat on personal level, that affect you directly**

Like fasting, prayer.. etc.

**Ibadaat with effect on the Muslim nation**

***has a greater reward***

Like zakat, sponsoring Orphans, spreading knowledge...etc

### Compulsory, (Unwillingly)

**No reward for this type**

Allah, Exalted He is, owns this universe, and what therein, everything does recognise and obeys its Lord, the body of an infidel is not his! if Allah wills He can command it to stop, die, or vanish. planets, trees, oceans, every single atom obeys, i.e worships, this is by compulsion or willingly.

e.g. prostration (ibaada)

> 13-15  And to Allah prostrates whoever is within the heavens and the
>   earth, **willingly or by compulsion**, and their shadows [as well] in the
>   mornings and the afternoons.

Another example

> 16:49 And to Allah prostrates whatever is in the heavens and whatever
>   is on the earth of creatures, and the angels [as well], and they are
>   not arrogant.

Exalting Him, another Ibaada

> 17:44 The seven heavens and the earth and whatever is in them exalt
>   Him. **And there is not a thing except that it exalts [ Allah ] by His
>   praise**, but you do not understand their [way of] exalting. Indeed, He
>   is ever Forbearing and Forgiving.

Shaytan doesn't pray (willingly), as he is fasiq, how can he pray if the prayer is meant to enjoin goodness and forbid evil ?

> 29:45 Recite, [O Muhammad], what has been revealed to you of the Book
>   and establish prayer. **Indeed, prayer prohibits immorality and
>   wrongdoing, and the remembrance of Allah is greater. And Allah knows
>   that which you do.**

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score -2):

No it doesn't.

The word praying means to obey the only one and indeed the One is Allah. Satan stopped praying to Allah. The day he refused to bow down to Adam (AS).

Satan is in direct fight with Allah SWT, so in no way he can pray to Allah.